# Client Reflected File Download Security Issue

Tags: javascript, security

I have a javascript code which has a securtiy issue saying "Client DOM Cookie Poisoning".

> An explicit filename is not defiend for Content-Disposition header file /Web/js/file.js. Filename attribute is required in order to prevent from browser to assume the resource is binary and download a possible malicious file.

`Code Snippet
File Name /Web/js/file.js
Method $(document).delegate("#Documents .listItem a", "click", function () {
....
251. $.getJSON(docWebMethod + "?jsonRequest=" + jsonRequest +
"&documentId=" + docId + "&ssoid=" + getCookie("id") + "&bbViewer=" +
bbViewer + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function (data) {`

I tried to fix this issue by adding a code in the class which above formed URL calls

> String headerUrl = "inline; filename=" + FilenameUtils.getName(fileName); response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", headerUrl);

but still it didn't work.Any idea how it can be fixed.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: @user2001627 No